# Prove that $(||x_n||)$ is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

If $(x_n)$ in  a Banach Space $X$ is such that $(f(x_n))$ is bounded for all $f\in X^{'}$,show that $(||x_n||)$ is bounded.

Actually  I found the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2086317/557708). But  im not satisfied  with the given answer

**My attempt** : let define   $\varphi_{x_n} : X^{'} \to \mathbb{F}$ such that $\varphi_{x_n}(f)=f(x_n)$

since  $f$ is linear  so $\varphi_{x_n} $ is a linear map

It is given that   $(f(x_n))$ is bounded so  we have $|\varphi_{x_n}(f)|= |f(x_n) |\le ||f||.||x_n|| \implies ||\varphi_{x_n}|| \le ||x_n||$

Now   by using  **Hahn Banach theorem**  there exist  $f \in X^{'}$ such that $|f(x_n)|=||x_n||$ and $||f||=1$

From $|f(x_n)|=||x_n||$ we have  $||\varphi_{x_n}|| = ||x_n||$

Set  $\{\varphi_{x_n}\}$ as  sequence  of  bounded linear  operator then  by **uniform boundedness theorem**  there exist  $M >0$ such that  $||\varphi_{x_n}|| \le M $

This implies  $||\varphi_{x_n}|| = ||x_n|| \le M$

Thus $(||x_n||)$ is bounded.

Is my proof  is correct  or not ?

Comment: @AlvinLepik $||\varphi_{x_n}(f)||$ is  bounded  for each $f$

Comment: Ah I get it. For every $f$ the inequality $|\varphi (f)| \leqslant \|f\|\cdot \|x_n\|$ holds. The norm is computed on the unit sphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line
$$|\varphi _{x_n}(f)| = |f(x_n)| \leqslant \|f\|\cdot \|x_n\| \Rightarrow \|\varphi _{x_n}\| \leqslant \|x_n\| $$
passes without invoking boundedness of $\{f(x_n)\}$. The inequalities hold for all $f\in X'$, in particular for those with unit norm.

It would help to specify how your variables are quantified. I think you are using the above inequalities for fixed $n$ and then also apply Hahn-Banach for fixed $n$, i.e for every $x_n$ we pick some $f_n$ such that so and so.